# Kafka Streams Code implemented as a library and function called

Tags: api, command, apache-kafka-streams, lib

So, I have created a Kafka Application that basically uses filter function. Now, I have created the jar file of this application.

I want to import this application as a library in some other program and call the method to start the filtering process. Then I also want to stop this filtering using some command or API call. How can I do this??

I have provide the topology builder function below for which I want to convert into a library and call from other application.

```java
public static Topology builderFunc(String id) {

    final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonNodeSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
    final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonNodeDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
    final Serde<JsonNode> jsonNodeSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonNodeSerializer, jsonNodeDeserializer);

    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    KStream<String, JsonNode> inputStream =
            builder.stream("input-records", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonNodeSerde));


    inputStream.filter((key, value) -> key.equals(id))
            .to("output-records", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), jsonNodeSerde));

    final Topology topology = builder.build();
    return topology;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I am unsure what you try to achieve. The way Kafka Streams is designed is to consume one/several topic(s) and produce messages in one/several topic(s). Usually KS apps run in a "standalone" mode, they are not in libs included in other applications. What would be the usecase to include the lib into another app? What do you try to achieve? Start and stop the full processing (ie no message is read from the input-records topic ? Or just enable/disable the filtering (messages are continuously consumed from input-records, but sometimes the filter is applied, sometimes not)?

Comment: Yes, So what I want is to enable/disable. Like the messages can be consumed but I want filtering to happen for some time. Lets says if I get 100 messages per second so i want to run the filter function only for 30 seconds and then I want to so other stuffs. But I want filtering for a short duration. I may start the filter again but then again if i need to stop I want some command that can stop it.

Comment: You start processing with `KafkaStreams#start()` and you can stop processing with `KafkaStreams#close()`.